# Difference between setContentPane(), doLayout() & setLayout() in a JFrame java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Can someone explain to me the following because I'm confused which to use & when: **setContentPane()**, **doLayout()** & **setLayout()** in a JFrame java.

Another query: Am I correct if I say that when using JFrame & other swing containers other than JPanel there is no need to set/create a content Pane manually but in others I'm required to set it manually ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: They are totally different methods. What is in the Javadoc that you can't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per java docs:

- [`setLayout(LayoutManager manager)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setLayout%28java.awt.LayoutManager%29)

> Sets the LayoutManager. Overridden to conditionally forward the call
>   to the contentPane.

So basically it allows us to set the `LayoutManager` of our `JFrame`s *contentPane*, as calling `setLayout(..)` on `JFrame` will be forwarded to *contentpane*.

- [`setContentPane(Container contentPane)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setContentPane%28java.awt.Container%29)

> Sets the contentPane property. This method is called by the
>   constructor. Swing's painting architecture requires an opaque
>   JComponent in the containment hiearchy. This is typically provided by
>   the content pane. If you replace the content pane it is recommended
>   you replace it with an opaque JComponent.

This refers to the main component added to our `JFrame` (and spans the `JFrame`s entire size), this is where all other components will be added on calls to `add(..)` on `JFrame` instance.

- [`doLayout()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#doLayout%28%29)

> Causes this container to lay out its components. Most programs should
>   not call this method directly, but should invoke the validate method
>   instead.

This will cause the visual changes to be shown when we changed the `LayoutManager` of a container, but as we can see we should not call this and rather use `validate()`/`revalidate()` followed by `repaint()` to make visual changes from size, re-layout and/or components added/removed froma container, visible.

As for:

> Am I correct if I say that when using JFrame & other swing containers
>   other than JPanel there is no need to set/create a content Pane
>   manually but in others I'm required to set it manually ?

No, this applies to `JPanel` too.

A `JPanel` is a `Container`, JFrame uses `setContentPane`, which allows us to set a container, thus `JPanel`/`JComponent` *extends* `Conatiner` so that it can be added as a *contentPane*. hence its exposure to the `setContentPane(..)` method.
A `JPanel` by default has a content pane or how else would we add components to it?

So thus no we dont have to manually create `JPanel` *contentPane*.

Answer (score 2):

setContentPane is used to set the top-level visual element inside a Window while setLayout sets a layout manager and doLayout invokes the layout manager. Normally doLayout doesn't need to be called because it is called automatically when major properties change, for example elements were added/removed or somthing resized.

I don't see any reason to be confused with these functions:

- If you want to add visual elements to your frame, use `setContentPane(component)` (or `add(component)`).
- If you want to set a Layout Manager (like `GridBagLayout` or `FlowLayout`), use `setLayout(layoutmanager)`.
- If you have changed something and your frame looks strange, call `doLayout()`.

Comment: Like Raffaele I also recommend to have a look to the Java documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html

Comment: You're right. I only didn't understand setContentPane() before, but now I do. Thanks for your help.